Spring Security Configuration Causes 'Too Many Redirects' Error - How to Resolve?
I am applying spring boot security. When I open the browser in the current code, it redirects infinitely to "http://localhost:8080/login" and shows the error "localhost redirected you too many times.".
Since formLogin() is deprecated, I used lambda expression.
This is the CustomSecurityConfig code:
package edu.library.libraryspringboot.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Log4j2
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("-----------------configuration---------------------");

        //http.formLogin();

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(formLogin -> {
                    formLogin
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .permitAll();
                });

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {

        log.info("---------------web configuration---------------------");
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations());
    }
}

And this is the CustomUserDetailsService code.
package edu.library.libraryspringboot.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Log4j2
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public CustomUserDetailsService() {
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        log.info("loadUserByUsername: " + username);

        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                .username("user1")
                //.password("1111")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("1111")) //Needs password encoding
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .build();

        return userDetails;
    }
}

I want to avoid the code from being infinitely redirected. How should I modify the code to see the login page?
Thank you in advance.

For starters re-use the same encoder else yo might endup with differences, you also might want to open /error for everyone. Finally enable debug logging to see what is happening.

Have you tried .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())? It looks like you are customizing the login page but you don't intend to.

Take a look at Spring Security 6 migration guide. If you are using Spring Boot 3.X and your /login page is from static folder, you should use .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll(), so your dispatcher / is not redirected to login and login to dispatcher indefinitely:
http
 .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
    authorize
        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
  })
  .formLogin(formLogin -> {
    formLogin
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll();
  });

